# How to prevent this exposure/tonal shift when stitiching an HDR panorama in Photoshop?

Tags: hdr, panorama, photoshop-cs5, image-stitching

I'm trying to create an HDR panorama.

I have 8 photos with 3 exposures each (-1, 0, +1 EV).
For each one, I used PS's merge to HDR functionality and chose 32 bit.

I have 8 files A, B, ...H.psd that I now want to merge to a panorama.
The stitiching works great, but the last image in the panorama is a lot darker in the panorama than it is on its own.

[image: single image and panorama]

On the left is the image on its own.
On the right, you see the part of the panorama that's made up of the image.
I added red outline around the contour of the mask for that image.

**Why is the image so much darker in the panorama?
How can I prevent this?**

I noticed that a lot of tools don't work in 32bit mode.
Is it recommended to stay in 32bit mdoe throughout the entire process?
Or **should I tonemap (or whatever it's called) each part of the panorama down to 8bit again and then stitch the panorama in 8 bit mode?**

Wait, we always take a second set of images in case something goes wrong, right?
Well, the second set of images produces even weirder results.
I only took 7 images (A-G). Take a look at the screenshot from PS that illustrates the problem below.

[image: single images and panorama]

The individual images on top have a similar look the exposure is the same.
I arranged the windows in a way that the single images mimic their position in the panorama.
The stitched panorama shows strange differences in exposure (?) throughout the panorama.

Wtf?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation on why one image becomes darker when merged, but perhaps "reversing" the process might help, first creating three panorama images, one per exposure setting (-1, 0, +1 EV), then running the HDR processing one those three images?

Comment: yes, that worked for my situation, still curious as to why it does the strange shifting